# Javascript/Angular- How to do string interpolation inside a variable or a class method?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, class, string-interpolation

I dont know if thats possible or not, but here is my ideia:

I have a class with methods and i want to present the method in a h1 Html component that matches the selected string.

Basically, i have a class of Pokemons, that each method is a pokemon, and i want to switch methods when my user select one type of pokemon.

Here is the code:

The service class (data) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GenIService {

  swampert = {
    hp: 138,
    atk: 121,
    def: 110.63,
    type: ' Water  Ground',

   };
}
```

The main page :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GenIService} from "../Pokemons/gen-i.service";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})


export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  genOne = [];

  button1clicked= false;
  button2clicked= false;

  pokemon1Selected = '';
  pokemon2Selected = '';

  constructor(private gen1: GenIService ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.gen1.swampert.hp);

  }

  buttonOneSelected() {
    this.button1clicked= true;
    this.button2clicked=false;
  }

  buttonTwoSelected() {
    this.button1clicked= false;
    this.button2clicked=true;
  }

  pokemon1SeletectedSwampert() {
    this.pokemon1Selected = "Swampert";

  }

  pokemon2SeletectedVenusaur(){
    this.pokemon2Selected = 'Venusaur';
  }
```

The Html code:

```
<ion-item>
         <ion-label>Name: {{}}</ion-label>
         <ion-label>HP: {{this.gen1.{pokemon1Selected}.hp}}</ion-label>
         <ion-label>ATK: {{}}</ion-label>
         <ion-label>DEF: {{}}</ion-label>
         <ion-label>Type: {{}}</ion-label>

    </ion-item>
```

So, in the Html code i am tring to have this variable = this.gen1.swampert.hp, but switch the pokemon name with the variable of pokemon1Selected, that in this case is equal to "Swampert".

How can i do that?

Comment: I would refactor to track the selected Pokemon with one variable.

Comment: But it is in one variable

Comment: `gen1` is an array, and you have `pokemon1Selected` and `pokemon2Selected`. If you can get a working example on stackblitz that would help out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your declaration genOne is an array so I'm not sure what you are trying to get when you call

`console.log(this.gen1.swampert.hp);`

If I understand correctly what you need is something like this (provided you add name property to your pokemon object)

.ts

```
public getPokemonOneSelected() {
    return this.genOne.find(x => x.name === this.pokemon1Selected);
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-label>HP: {{this.getPokemonOneSelected()?.hp}}</ion-label>
```

That '?.' is to prevent error if .find() returns *undefined*

As Phix pointed out it would be better to track selected pokemon with just 1 variable so instead of

```
 pokemon1Selected = '';
 pokemon2Selected = '';
```

just have

```
selectedPokemon = '';
...
public getSelectedPokemon() {
    return this.genOne.find(x => x.name === this.selectedPokemon);
}
...
<ion-label>HP: {{this.getSelectedPokemon()?.hp}}</ion-label>
```